# Add external link to Facebook page tab list

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

So here's an image of what my Facebook fan page sidebar currently looks like:

[image]

Underneath the Tumblr tab, I'd like to add a link that says "My Blog" and when users click on it they're brought to my website. I do NOT want it to open a new tab on my facebook page, I simply want it to be an external link. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you're trying is not possible!
You can't add external links as tabs, the only way is to simply create an app which simply redirects to your site and add it to your facebook page, if you don't want to create a new app and do all those stuffs, then the simple way is to use this app: https://www.facebook.com/iframehost?sk=app_208195102528120

It has built in feature for redirecting to external sites, just add this app to your page, authorize it and then select redirect and add your site URL and you're done.

Comment: Great, thanks @dennis-m, I'll give that app a try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @Mike: No problem, let me know if you want me to help you with anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it works perfectly! I found another app that did something similar, but it was much more buggy. Your recommendation is a much better solution.